# How do you use the revealing module pattern with jQuery's document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, revealing-module-pattern, self-executing-function

I have the following (albeit) small 'revealing module pattern' implementing code:

```
(function (CkSpace, $, undefined) {

    CkSpace.GetLoanValues = function () {
        var url = "/Home/UpdateAPR";

        $.get(url, { Amount: $("#slider").slider("value"), Length: $("#slider2").slider("value") }, function (data) {
            $("#LoanAmount").html("£"+data.LoanAdvance);
            $("#TotalToRepay").html("£" + data.LoanGrossRepayable);
            $("#Representative").html(data.LoanAPR);
            $("#MonthlyRepayTerm").html(data.LoanTerm);
            $("#MonthlyFee").html("£" + data.LoanInstalment);
        });
    }

} (window.CkSpace = window.CkSpace || {}, jQuery));
```

I was under the impression that by using `window.CkSpace` I would be able to access CkSpace globally as a root namespace for any of its public members. However, when I used this in conjunction with `$(document).ready()` I was unable to access my `CkSpace` namespace unless I declared it within `$(document).ready()`.

Could someone explain to me the scoping issue here and if there is anyway to avoid declaring it inside my `$(document).ready()` function?

**EDIT: I was being a bit forgetful it seems and I wasn't prefixing CkSpace with window when accessing it within the scope of `$(document).ready()`**

Comment: Can you amend this code so its the code that _doesn't_ work. I've had no problem getting this code + a document ready function to work properly. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hi Andy. I've sorted the problem out, I wasn't prefixing CkSpace with window before attempting to access it. Clearly I need more caffeine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ben,

If I have understood your concern, This code snippet might help you.

```
window.CkSpace = {};

(function (CkSpace) {

    CkSpace.getLoanValues = function () {
       alert('I provide loans');
    }

} (window.CkSpace || {}, jQuery));

window.CkSpace.getLoanValues();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GDcVt/

If not can you please make it more minimal as the internal code has no relevance with scope. I am not sure whether the objcet does exist in the window scope before you pass it to the function.

Comment: Hello Pallab. I was trying to access CkSpace without prefixing it with window. Your code helped me realise that so thanks.